How to resolve scikit-build-core and vcpkg integration issues for building C++ Python extensions on Windows?
I'm trying to build a Python extension module using scikit-build-core, pybind11 and vcpkg, but I'm encountering issues when setting up the build environment. Here's what I've done so far:

Installed vcpkg and set the toolchain file.
Configured scikit-build-core with the following command: pipx run build
Added the necessary vcpkg libraries to the find_package command in my CMakeLists.txt.

However, the build fails with the following error:
vcpkg/scripts/tls12-download.exe is not recognised as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program
I've tried the following without success:

Rechecking vcpkg library paths.
Ensuring the vcpkg.cmake toolchain is in the correct location.
Updating both vcpkg and scikit-build-core.
Changed build-dir so that I could inspect the logs

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Native Python module on Ubuntu 24.04
screenshot
